# Does teamcity support polling of ECR repo for new image version?

Tags: teamcity, amazon-ecr

I am trying to setup teamcity job that polls AWS ECR repo to check if a newer version of an image is available and if so re-deploy application on on-premises servers.

I have got bitbucket pipeline that build docker image on commit in the specific branch and push these images to AWS ECR repository.

The servers are on-premises and want to deploy newly created image on it using teamcity. However, I couldn't find a way in teamcity that would poll ECR repository for newer image versions.

Is there way to do this using teamcity? If there is no way of doing this then we have to go with schedule job unless experts out there suggest a better way of doing it.

Comment: use webhooks, send webhook to TeamCity to start the specific configuration after bitbucket pipeline

Comment: Thanks Senior Pomidor. I will try it out and report back on the development.